# std::vector const elements change

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants, std

I have a strange problem where elements in a std::vector gets changed even though they're set as const. The code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < simLength ; i++) {
    const meshType m = meshType(*(simulator->getMesh()));
    meshes.push_back(m);

    printMeshes();
    simulator->tick();
    printMeshes();
}
```

Further up the vector is declared as

```
std::vector<meshType> meshes;
```

I have fairly routine experience with C++ but I still get caught on some basic
errors from time to time. This looks like it could be one of them but I'm not sure.

The problem is that when I add a mesh and print it, it looks fine, but when the simulator ticks and I print it again, it have changed to the mesh that is currently in the simulator.
This made me suspect I was saving a pointer, but I cannot for the life of me find out how.

I orignaly did not push const objects, but changed it in a desperate gambit to make it work.

Any tips would be appriciated.

== EDIT ==

The meshType is a typedef of the mmesh class which contains a copy constructor:

```
MFloatPointArray* vertices;
MIntArray* faceCounts;
MIntArray* faceConnects;

mmesh::mmesh(const gmesh& orig) {
    vertices = new MFloatPointArray(*orig.getVertices());
    faceCounts = new MIntArray(*orig.getFaceCounts());
    faceConnects = new MIntArray(*orig.getFaceConnects());
}
```

Comment: Does your `meshType` implement proper copy semantics? `vector::push_back` copies the element into the vector. The `const` you added would have no effect here.

Comment: I have created a copy constructor for the mesh if that is what you mean (see edit in question). If not, an explenation would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector`, as it grows on the fly and is sequential. That requires copying/moving following a reallocation, can not be used with const types directly. You either need to use vector of pointers so that only pointers will be moved around instead of objects or some other container like `std::deque` that does not require the elements to be moved/copied unless you `erase` an element, or a container like `std::list` that does not move/copy an element ever.

`list.push_back(e)` will copy the `e` element you give as the argument to inside the vector so the new element inside `list` won't be `const`. You need to define your container as `std::list<const meshType>` but then if anything modifies element inside the container you won't be able to compile the code.

Any member functions will be assumed to be modifying the class if they are not marked const in declaration and definition. On const objects you can only call methods that are marked as const:

In header file:

```
class A
{
 ...
 size_t getSomething() const;
}
```

And in source file:

```
A::getSomething() const
{ ... }
```

Further information:

`const` functions can only alter variables that are declared `mutable`.

When you define the class object as `const`, `vertices` pointer will be const but not the data it points to. Something can't assign a new address to `vertices` but it can modify what it points to. You will still need to define it as `const Type* vertices;`, without you putting const there, it is `Type* const vertices;` if the object is `const`.

Comment: I have tried to mark the type as const meshType but this does not change anything sadly. And the methods used are all marked const so it should be ok. Which again makes me think think its pointers, thats usually where I go wrong anyway.

Comment: @Martinnj I have edited the answer a bit. Is what getting changed marked `mutable`? If it is not and something still modifies elements of `std::vector<const meshType>` then maybe whatever modifying it uses `const_cast` to cast away constness (`const_cast` on already constructed classes is undefined behavior).

Comment: No, the values that change are the content in the MFloatPointArray in the mmesh. (the vertices array in the edited question).

Comment: You can't (reasonably) make a vector of const objects. Elements need to be assignable. You'd have to have a const assignment operator, which is just ridiculous.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Will using `emplace` and move operator not be enough?

Comment: Then you'd have to have a move constructor which takes a const r-value reference, which is also ridiculous.

Comment: Indeed I am. It's contained in a visual C++ project. So there should be no mistakes. I have begun looking at implementing a override for the = operator though.

Comment: @Martinnj I have re-read the question after the edit and edited the answer to point out something.

Comment: Making vertices const is not an option since the simulator should be able to modify its own internal mesh, just not the ones stored in the vector.

Comment: Then you will need to create a separate interface that only allows you to read the `vertices` by keeping an internal reference to actual object and returning const reference to the `vertices` member.